# Always respond with a specific response for set of IPs

Tags: nginx

I'm running nginx server and I'm getting tons of bots who request `/admin.php` files, even though I never even installed PHP in the first place. So I decided that I will, instead of simply blocking those bots, setup a surprise for them. I have *really* big gzip-compressed file that I send to every request for `.php`, `.aspx`, `/admin` and so on.

```
    location ~ (admin)|(wp-admin)|(\.php)|(.aspx) {
            proxy_pass              http://localhost:8085;

            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Protocol    $scheme;
    }
```

(I have server running at `:8085` that just sends the big compressed blob.)

Now, I discovered an IP address from Panama that keeps sending SQL injections my way. And they are doing it so much, they permanently sit on top of requests from clients in my logs all the time.

I could block them, but that wouldn't be fun. **How do I always proxy_pass all requests from specific IP(s)?** No matter the target resource or hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` block and a special [internal](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal) location (which would be accessible only after internal URI rewrite):

```
map $remote_addr $block {
    A.B.C.D  1;
    E.F.G.H  1;
    ...
}
server {
    ...
    if ($block) {
        rewrite ^ /surprise last;
    }
    rewrite (admin|wp-admin|\.php|\.aspx) /surprise last;
    location = /surprise {
        internal;
        proxy_pass              http://localhost:8085;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Protocol    $scheme;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! It looks much more elegant than my past one. Works perfectly.